# Migration from Windows XP

Tags: wine, lubuntu

I have started using Ubuntu and I'm very impressed by it's performance. I want to install Lubuntu on a 10 year old PC with a 2.66GHz Celeron CPU with 1.5Gb of RAM. It has PAE capabilities. It will only be used for web browsing and office.

Given that the users are not Linux experts and prefer a Windows like experience is there any desktop which resembles windows as to make the transition easier?

If I install Unity and Wine later will that degrade that advantages of Lubuntu? Excuse these questions but I am on a learning curve right now.

Thanks,

Joseph

Comment: Lubuntu is fairly Windows-like(more so than gnome or unity) or Xubuntu is about the same in that respect, both of which you can run on your computer.  Of the officially supported flavors, Kubuntu is the most Windows-like in my opinion, but you may have a problem running KDE on an older computer.

Answer (score 1):

You probably won't be able to use Unity on that machine, it's too old. But you can use Lubuntu or Ubuntu without Unity.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Lubuntu. My machines are old and they run very smooth with Lubuntu. The users coming from Windows XP will be familiarized with the new OS in a very short time. Unity on older machines could cause some slow down issues due to the consumption of resources. On the other side, Wine won't cause any degradation, as long as the applications you are planning to run under Wine are not too heavy.

Answer (score 0):

I have Lubuntu running on a P3-1.12 Ghz , 512MB RAM and it flies. 
On my Celeron 2.4 Ghz , 1GB RAM, KDE was noticably sluggish so I tried both the XFCE & LXDE Desktops (which is default for Lubuntu), and they work great.

IMHO - Mint Linux is the most Windows like, in my experience.